# Modify data incoming to django form before cleaning

Tags: python, django

I need do modify data incoming to `Form` before cleaning. I made it work, but It looks awful:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if len(args) > 0:
            data = args[0]
        elif 'data' in kwargs:
            data = kwargs['data']
        else:
            data = None
        if data is not None:
            data['content'] = ' '.join(data['content'].strip().split())
        super(TagForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is there some laconic solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compress the `if` / `elif` / `else` onto one line easily enough:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    data = args[0] if args else kwargs.get('data', None)
    if data:
        data['content'] = ' '.join(data['content'].strip().split())
    super(TagForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

`if args` works as well as `if len(args) > 0` because `length == 0` items are `False` and `length > 0` items are `True`.

`if data` works as well as `if data is not None` because you're assuming that `data` has at least one key if it's `not None` anyway, and if it has a key it's `True`.

Comment: It works fine, thanks. But I read in PEP 8 that using `is` or `is not` with `None` is better for code styling.

Comment: You asked for the `laconic` solution, so I shortened it as much as possible. In this case, `False` and `is None` have the same effect, In many situations you only want to treat `None` as `None`, so you should use `is` to avoid accidentally thinking `False` is `None`.

Comment: @Yuriy PEP 8 also suggests to use `if args` instead of `if len(args) > 0` in your original code, which uses the fact that empty sequences are false.

Comment: 'data' needs to be surrounded by quotes inside the if statement. To make it even shorter, you could use *data = args and args[0] or kwargs.get('data', None)*.

Comment: @Nasmon Thanks, shortened. `and` / `or` instead of `if` / `else` is bad style and not any shorter. It also has different behavior when `args[0]` is false.

Comment: Technically, it works great, but the changed data is not passed to super and the form keeps the old data.

Comment: @raratiru What do you mean? We're modifying data in place, so the args passed to `super` will include the updated item.

Comment: I tried it and indeed the values of `data` are the expected but at the end, the `modelForm` uses the initial data. Then I tested this case: `>>a = [1, 2]` `>>b = a[0]` `>>b = 2`when I called `a` again it did not return `[2, 2]`. [Alasdair's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11083656/2996101) explicitly sends `data` to `super()` and the result is OK. Is there a way to set the value of `b` and actually set the value of `a[0]`?

Comment: @raratiru That isn't equivalent. You're just manipulating names, not actually mutating any objects. Here is what is actually happening: ```>>> args = [{"content": "foo"}]
>>> data = args[0]
>>> data["content"] = "bar"
>>> args
[{'content': 'bar'}]
```

Comment: OK, this is obvious. It must have gone something else wrong and I got confused. Thank you, anyway for the clarification.

Comment: For the typical use case, `form = MyForm(request.POST)`, the querydict `request.POST` is immutable, so you can't modify in place. In my answer I do `data = data.copy()` to get a mutable querydict.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you then, this is the reason why this solution did not work when I implemented it.

Comment: @Alasdair I'm a little confused. I haven't used Django in years, so can't easily test this. But if the object is immutable, wouldn't it raise an exception? What raratiru is describing is it silently failing.

Answer (score 7):

Make `data` the first argument of the `__init__` method, the same as the super class `Form`. That way you don't have to dig about in `args` or `kwargs`.

```
def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if data is not None:
        data = data.copy() # make it mutable
        data['content'] = ' '.join(data['content'].strip().split())
    super(TagForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: In Django 1.11 I receive the following error: `super().__init__(data=data, *args, **kwargs)` `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'data'`

Comment: @raratiru that's not enough information to be able to help you, please ask a new question.

Comment: Indeed, it is a very old post anyway, thank you for responding.

Comment: I found it! The `data=data` part of the `super()` line causes the error. The following works great: `super(TagForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: In a fresh Django install, I have registered a model with one `CharField` in the admin and I attached the following form: `class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):` `def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):` `super().__init__(data=data, *args, **kwargs)`. It gives the error when I enter a random letter and hit `save`.

Comment: @raratiru You're right. The Django admin passes `request.FILES` as an argument, so we need to change `data` to a positional argument to avoid the `TypeError`. I've updated the answer as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution:

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    data = dict(self.data)
    if 'content' in data:
        content = data['content']
        if isinstance(content, list):
            content = content[0] # QueryDict wraps even single values to list
        data['content'] = ' '.join(content.strip().split())
    self.data = data # I do this trick becouse request.POST is immutable
    return super(MyForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

UPD: error fix: `super(self.__class__, self)` may cause infinite recursion if I use form inheritance :).

UPD: seems still have troubles, and not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation for form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/) you can not do it on form level, so the `__init__` method seems the most legit way. You can of course also modify the data before passing it to the form (for example in your view or wherever you process the form).