# How to use TextInput widget with ModelChoiceField in Django forms?

Tags: python, django, forms

In Django, the `ChoiceField` or `ModelChoiceField` represent the data in a `Select` widget. This is helpful when the list of objects is small. However it is extremely difficult to manage (for the end-user) if the number of objects are in thousands.

To eliminate the said problem I'd like the end-users to manually enter the field value in an input box of type text (i.e, via `TextInput` widget).

---

So far, I have created the below code. As `ModelChoiceField` has `Select` widget by default; It behaves in similar manner as before even after changing the widget to `TextInput`. It expects a `pk` or `id` value of the model object and thus raising an error :

> *Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.*

However, I'd want the end-user to enter `sku_number` field in the input box rather than the `pk` or `id` of the object. What is the correct way to solve this problem?

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    sku_number = models.CharField(null=False, unique=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(null=Flase)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sku_number
```

**forms.py**

```
class SkuForm(forms.Form):
    sku_number = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all(), 
                                        widget=forms.TextInput())
    extra_field = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

---

**Note** : I did try another approach to solve this problem. By displaying only last 10 objects by slicing the number of objects; this ensures that the select box is not flooded with thousands of items.

```
queryset=Product.objects.all().order_by('-id')[:10]
```

The latter methodology if correctly implemented would work with my particular use-case, however others might be interested in the former method. The above statement further raised errors because of Django's limitation with generating SQL statements.

> Also note that even though slicing an unevaluated **QuerySet** returns another unevaluated **QuerySet**, modifying it further (e.g., adding more filters, or modifying ordering) is not allowed, since that does not translate well into SQL and it would not have a clear meaning either.
>
> Source : [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)

Comment: Are you primarily concerned about the difficulty of navigating that many options, or are there so many options that it's negatively impacting your page load time? If you're just looking to make form navigation easier and you don't mind an outside dependency, chosen.js might be worth looking into.

Comment: @souldeux My primary concern is about the difficulty of navigating that many options. Talking about scaling, I am not really sure if (at max) 10K objects in a select drop-down will hit performance or page load-time. **Edit** : 10K in a single select drop-down would be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I had to change the `sku_number` field to Product object's `id`. This had to be done before `clean()`. As seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11083656/433587), `__init__()` should be used to modify data before it reaches `clean()`.

```
class SkuForm(forms.Form):
    sku_number = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all(), 
                                        widget=forms.TextInput())
    extra_field = forms.CharField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if data is not None:
            data = data.copy() # make it mutable
            if data['sku_number']:
                obj = get_object_or_404(Product, batch_name=data['sku_number'])
                data['sku_number'] = obj.id
        super(SkuForm, self).__init__(data=data, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that in the form clean() method.

I.e.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class SkuForm(forms.Form):
    sku = forms.CharField(required=True)
    extra_field = forms.CharField(required=True)

    def clean(self):
        # If you're on Python 2.x, change super() to super(SkuForm, self)
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        sku = cleaned_data['sku']
        obj = get_object_or_404(Product, sku_number=sku)
        # do sth with the Product
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not exactly sure (as of yet) what your answer suggests. The form submits successfully when `pk` of the Product model is entered. However, it still won't accept the `sku_number` raising a `KeyError`. Part of the problem might be, that `def clean(self):` doesn't return anything, but I did try returning `return self.cleaned_data`.

Comment: I tried this and failed.. `obj = get_object_or_404(Product, sku_number=sku);
        self.cleaned_data['sku_number'] = obj.id`

Comment: @SurajThapar Sorry mate, I updated the code snippet. Didn't remember it correctly last night.