# Textinput with ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, django-forms

I yesterday asked this question without success but I have still been working on the problem. [Save user input which is a string as object in db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71413813/save-user-input-which-is-a-string-as-object-in-db)
. In short the question yesterday described how I wanted to have a registration key in my registration form to be able to restrict who can register themselves.

What I have done now is in the forms.py file have I created a key field as a ModelChoiceField with a textinput as the widget. When I write a key which exists in the DB I get the following error: "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.". I can't use Select as the widget as that would display the keys for the users.

I tried both methods in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39191861/how-to-use-textinput-widget-with-modelchoicefield-in-django-forms) post but without any success.

So the question know is, how can I have a TextInput with a ModelChoiceField?

Answer (score 1):

Get the string from the user through a form with a CharField. Assuming you are using the CBV `FormView`, do the work in the `form_valid` method. Something like:

```
def form_valid( self, form):
    key = form.cleaned_data['key']
    try:
        keyobj = Keything.objects.get( key=key)
        # it's valid. do whatever.
        return super().form_valid( form)
    except Keything.DoesNotExist:
        form.add_error( 'key', 'This is not a valid key')
        return super().form_invalid( form)
```

Alternatively you could have a Validator on the form's `key` field which raises `ValidationError` if the `Keything` object does not exist.

Comment: This returns the error that the input in the key field can't be assign to User.key and that it has to be an RegistrationKey instance. I have added my form in the post. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RandomMadi as stated it's supposed to be a method of the Class-Based view `FormView`, not a method of the form. If you want to check in the form, use a validator.

Comment: Oh I missed that completely, my bad. I am using function based view though. Should I change to a CBV?

Comment: I prefer CBVs but you can do logically the same thing in a FBV. Check, add an error to the form if the check fails, and transfer to the form_invalid code path. It's probably harder to code than switching to CBVs, though. Using a custom validator might be the way to go.

Comment: Alright I will try and swith to a CBV. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @RandomMadi just spotted error, should be `add_error("key"` e.g. the name of the field. About to edit.

Comment: I switched to CBV but I still get the same error, that the input can not assigned to "User.key" and that it has to be a "RegistrationKey" instance. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: @RandomMadi you need to post the code of your view, form, and relevant parts of the model definition(s). Also, the error message and line where it occurs. Suggest, as another question.